# "get used to cycle" or "get used to cycling"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I tried to pass an exam at www.newschool.co.uk site.
One of the questions was to choose correct variant among phrases:

A: I just can’t get used to cycle on the left-hand side of the road!

B: I just can’t used to cycle on the left-hand side of the road!

C: I just can’t get used to cycling on the left-hand side of the road!

D: I don’t get used to cycling on the left-hand side of the road!

I choosed A but the site said that the correct variant was C. In school I was taught that the gerund (-ing) cannot be used with the particle 'to", while infinitive needs it. Have the grammar rules changed in the last 40 years?

Comment: The rule you were taught in school is not a good one.  I can think of many contexts where the word _to_ can appear before a gerund.  This is just one case.  Incidentally, (D) could be correct here too, in certain contexts.  I would never use (A) or (B) - they both seem wrong to me.

Comment: One thing that has certainly not changed in the past 40 years is the past participle of the verb _to choose!_

Comment: It's the "get" bit which probably threw you off your bike. If the sentence had started with **I am not used to...** you would have seen that *used* was *being used* differently from how you **were** probably **used  to** seeing it (groan).

Answer (score 14):

No, this aspect of grammar has not changed, but the rule you state only applies to one usage of *used to*.  But in fact ["used to" has two definitions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to).

When *used to* is used as a verb, then your grammatical analysis is correct -- it must be followed by an infinitive.  This is what you would do when indicating that an action took place in the past (often or habitually).

> I used to wake up every morning at 7, but now that winter is here, I can sleep in until 9!

However, *used to* can also be an adjective, indicating *familiarity with something*.  In this case, "to" is a preposition rather than an infinitive marker, and the phrase is followed by a *noun*, indicating what you are familiar with.  It may be that you are accustomed to performing some action; in this case you would use the gerund of that verb.

> I'm used to American English, so some British conventions sound very strange to me.
>
> He's used to his parents spoiling him; he'll have a hard time in the real world.

The latter usage is what's being used in your example.  We can tell that *used to* can't be the verb here, because the main verb of the sentence, *get*, is already present.

Comment: +1 And of course, the student's understanding of this distinction is exactly what the exam question is meant to test for...

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. However, in the phrase "I love to cycle" the main verb "love" does not forbid using of another verb, "cycle".

Comment: @rfq "Love to [infinitive]" is a _verb._ "Used to [sth]" in your examples is meant to be an _adjective,_ not a verb. That is why answer A is incorrect, and why answer C is correct. "Used to" as an adjective modifies a noun or noun phrase (in this case the _gerund_ of "cycle") and not an infinitive. The "to" in "used to" here is _not_ an infinitive marker for the verb "cycle". It doesn't belong to the verb; it's part of the adjectival phrase "used to".

Comment: @rfq That's true, but *used to* wouldn't be able to be used in the same way because it doesn't have an infinitive.  As a verb, it is always in the past tense.  Something like "I get to used to cycle" wouldn't make sense.